# create dynamic route Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
 Route::get('/', function () {

    $session = Session::get('request');
    $i=2;

    foreach ($session as $sessions){
        if ($i == 3){
            Route::get('/{'.$sessions.'}', 'SearchController@search_advance');
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

I am trying to create dynamic route according to my given data but blank page is show please help me if you can
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQINQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure what you trying to achieve but why not you validate it in "search_advance" function

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    Route::get('{session}', 'SearchController@search_advance');
});
```

in controller

```
public function search_advance(Request $request, $session)
{
    // If you want to test,
    // http://localhost:8000/your_url/A
    // http://localhost:8000/your_url/B
    // http://localhost:8000/your_url/C

    echo $session // result: A/B/C
}
```

Comment: will you please explain it ??